# Get All Items of a list regardless the approval status

Tags: list, versioning, item

I'm creating a page showing all items from a list. I have enabled versioning for that list.
So I want to show the list of all items, even pending items, when a user with contribute permissions is logged in.

```
DataTable dtserviceDetailsItems = serviceDetailsList.Items.GetDataTable();
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution :)

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId))
            {
                thisWeb = site.OpenWeb();
                SPList serviceDetailsList = thisWeb.Lists["Service Details"];
                if (serviceDetailsList.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataTable dtserviceDetailsItems = serviceDetailsList.GetItems().GetDataTable();
                    dtserviceDetailsItems.Columns.Add("Profile", typeof(string));
                    dtserviceDetailsItems.Columns.Add("Topic", typeof(string));
                    gvServices.DataSource = GetSortedData(dtserviceDetailsItems, gvSortExpression, gvSortDirection);
                    gvServices.DataBind();
                }
            }
        });
```

using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {}